# Yii2 url rewrite suffix (php) issue

Tags: php, .htaccess, nginx, yii2

I Have some url pattern that should work on my website.

```
[
'pattern'=>'page/result',
'route'=>'site/index',
'suffix'=>'.html'
],
[
'pattern'=>'page/result',
'route'=>'site/index',
'suffix'=>'.php'
],
```

In these two url suffix .html is working fine but .php suffix is not working in MY Nginx Server. Also check the my site nginx setting.

```
server {


listen 8081 default_server;
    listen [::]:8081 default_server;

    root /var/www/html/yii2project/frontend/web;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html index.php;


    access_log  /var/log/yii2/access.log;
    error_log   /var/log/yii2/error.log;

    server_name yii2.local;

    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        #try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
           root   /var/www/html/yii2/frontend/web;
           index  index.html index.htm index.php;
           try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;#now
           #rewrite ^/(.*)$ /$1 last;
           #if ($http_host ~* "^yii2.local:8081"){
           #rewrite ^(.*)$ http://www.yii2.local:8081$1 redirect;
            #}

       }

        #caching of static files
        location ~*  \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|css|js)$ {
           expires 365d;
        }


    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    #
    location ~ \.php$ {
    #   include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    #
    #   # With php5-cgi alone:
    #   fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    #   # With php5-fpm:
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /usr/share/nginx/html$fastcgi_script_name;               # include fastcgi.conf;
                include fastcgi.conf;#now 
        fastcgi_read_timeout 300;    

    } 
}
```

http://yii2.local:8081/page/result.html (working)
http://yii2.local:8081/page/result.php (not working)

Please see the nginx setting and tell me where i'm wrong configurartion.

Answer (score 0):

You have three different document roots which seems a little strange:

```
/var/www/html/yii2project/frontend/web
/var/www/html/yii2/frontend/web
/usr/share/nginx/html
```

The first will be used to locate resource files (`.css` and `.js`). The second will be used to locate `.html` files. The third will be used to locate `.php` files.

Assuming that all of your files share a common root, it is usual to place a `root` directive in the `server` block and allow all `location` blocks to inherit the value.

You should probably change the value of your first `root` directive. Delete the `root` directive in the `location /` block, and change the definition of `SCRIPT_FILENAME`.

```
server {
    ...
    root /var/www/html/yii2/frontend/web;
    ...
    location / { ... }
    location ~*  \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|css|js)$ { ... }
    location ~ \.php$ {
        ...
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }
}
```

Comment: By mistaken i write /var/www/html/yii2project/frontend/web my root path is this /var/www/html/yii2/frontend/web and i'm using apache and nginx on 8081 port so in nginx sites-available default file i'll set only one project in nginx server only. also change the fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name; and its not working.